# o que significa dar clear em uma variável do tipo Calendar?

Tags: java

Eu quero saber quando eu devo utilizar o clear() e porque usar.

```java
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormart = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date data1 = simpleDateFormart.parse("18/12/1986");
Date data2 = simpleDateFormart.parse("25/01/2017");

Calendar mD = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar mD2 = Calendar.getInstance();

mD.clear();
mD2.clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

O método [clear()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#clear()) coloca todos os campos do Calendar e o seu valor(time value) como "indefinido".
Isso implica que o método `isSet()` de qualquer campo retorna `false`.

O valor "indefinido" é um detalhe de cada implementação, por exemplo o GregorianCalendar usa *January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT*<sup>(1)</sup>.

Tendo como exemplo o código que postou, após `mD.clear();` `mD.YEAR` será 1970.

<sub>Fonte: [Class Calendar.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)</sub>

<sub><sup>(1) Em computação o tempo é contado tendo como referência este ponto no tempo([Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date))/[Época](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89poca_(cronologia))). Qualquer outro ponto no tempo é definido em relação a ele e representado como a diferença em milissegundos entre eles.</sup></sub>

Comment: Nossa...não entendi nada...será que sou muito burra? 1970? De onde veio esse valor?

Comment: Veja a nota que adicionei à resposta. Veja [isto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Era_Unix) também.

Comment: ok. só um momento que irei ler. E venho aqui falar com o senhor. espera...